# Why python for loop stops at the first instance of iteration?

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, boto3, rds

I'm updating python function for getting a list of rds instances with 'Backup' tag set to "true" but for some reason the for loop stops at the first instance.

We have 10 rds instances.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's the code:

```
def get_instances(region)
    rds = boto3.client('rds', region)
    instances_to_snapshot = []

    response = rds.describe_db_instances()

    aurora = "aurora"
    oracle = "oracle-se1"
    aurora_list = []

    instances = response['DBInstances']
    for instance in instances:
        engine = instance['Engine']
        if get_rds_instance_tag(region, instance['DBInstanceIdentifier'], 'Backup'):
            print "This instance - %s has engine - %s " % (instance['DBInstanceIdentifier'], engine)
            instances_to_snapshot.append(instance['DBInstanceIdentifier'])
    return instances_to_snapshot
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. I'm going to guess you either have your return indented wrong in your actual code, putting it inside the loop, or the list actually only has 1 element.

Comment: I'd try adding some basic logging: `print(len(instances))` before you go into the for loop, and `print("Entering loop")` on the line after the for loop.

Comment: I updated the code and tried adding it in here but I can't figure it out the formatting, so I pasted the code in pastebin https://pastebin.com/zHdD659d

Comment: The result is in another pastebin: https://pastebin.com/WThP0B0g but again it stops after it goes through the first item in the list.

Comment: Can you share the resulting `response` & `instances` variables? verify it contains more than one instance, as mentioned by others your code looks fine.

Comment: This behavior is really weird because function doesn't work correctly only when I run it from lambda environment but when I run it locally from EC2 it works fine and executes with expected behavior. Immediately I checked IAM role/policy and even allowed access to all resources & actions but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!! The issue was 'Time out' setting in lambda.. haha It was set to "3 seconds" No wonder function didn't work correctly.